# Query to get data of a post, if in category?

Tags: posts, wp-query, sql

You would think you could use

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'p' => $idofpost,
    'cat' => $numbers
));
```

to return the post if it is a certain category (or categories, or -number to exclude a category).

Oddly enough it always returns the post, and looking at `$query->request` it looks like the sql it runs has no mention of category/taxonomy at all.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Post some more code, like how you get $numbers variable.

Comment: @RajeevVyas It doesn't matter if it is 'x', or '-x', x being number of category to exclude. It always returns the post.

Comment: read @PieterGoosen's Answer. He explained it very well. If you use `p` then all other parameters are ignored. If you want to check for category then you should check it before the query.

Comment: It is true what @Roberthue said, you will need to somehow filter your I'd before your query of filter the returned list of posts from your query

Comment: @Roberthue Not all other parameters are ignored. Post status publish can be filtered here for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your query won't work as it will simply ignore your taxonomy query. This is not a bug but expected behavior.

When using `p` as your parameter, every other query parameter are ignored/bypassed like for example `post_type`, `tax_query` and any taxonomy related queries like category and tag parameters due to the fact that you are directly querying specific posts by reference.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but you need to have a look at [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and all of its available parameters and use those that are directly relevant to what you need. Also, this can be a structural or planning problem on your side which will maybe need you to rethink what you are trying to do and achieve

**EDIT**

From the comments

> That sort of makes sense, but actually has_password, post_status, maybe others, will correctly filter whether or not to return the post in this case

That you have to go and play around with and check the SQL request. AFAIK, if you directly querying a post with `p`, it will return the post regardless. I still don't fully understand what exactly happens within the `WP_Query` class.

The current [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/query.php#L828) for the `WP_Query` class compromise of **3716 lines** of code, that is excluding the first section in the `query.php` file where the conditional functions are defined

That is way too much to wrap your head around. IMHO, I think the best way will be to do some test yourself and test different scenarios and checking that against the source code. I don't really believe that this is a day's work.  You will go mad if you really try and understand and know what is happening in `WP_Query` in a day or two, maybe also a month :-)

Comment: That sort of makes sense, but actually `has_password`, `post_status`, maybe others, will correctly filter whether or not to return the post in this case.